# `plocate` couldn't find results in my home dir but `mlocate` could. How to search results in home dir?

Tags: locate, updatedb

Currently I'm trying to migrate from `mlocate` to `plocate`.

I'm using `mlocate` in my script (note: `locate` is aliased to either `mlocate` or `plocate` depending which one I've installed).

### Successfully searched home directory with `mlocate`

Below is the first 10 outputs after running `locate home` (locate is aliased to `mlocate`):

```
/home
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/site.local
/etc/systemd/homed.conf
/home/username
/home/username/.bash_history
/home/username/.bash_profile
/home/username/.bashrc
/home/username/.cache
/home/username/.cargo
```

As you can see, I could successfully find files in my home directories with `mlocate`.

### Unsuccessfully searched home directory with `plocate`:

However, after installing `plocate`, I get results from `/etc/`, `/usr/` etc, and all I get is one `/home`:

After running `locate home` (`locate` is aliased to `plocate`):

```
/home
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/site.local
/etc/systemd/homed.conf
/usr/bin/addgnupghome
/usr/bin/homectl
```

As you can see, `plocate` couldn't find files and directories in my home directory.

### What I've tried

#### 1. Comment from author of `plocate`

This manjaro thread [How to use plocate?](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/how-to-use-plocate/82592) has the author of `plocate` commented as below:

> First, check that the database has been updated recently. Most users will want to use plocate’s updatedb; plocate-build (which converts from mlocate’s database) is generally not what you want since plocate 1.1.0. [...]
>
> The other reason why a file isn’t shown, is typically permissions. Check if you can find the files as root (sudo plocate test); if you can, the problem is most likely that you don’t have access rights to the directory all the way down from the root. plocate should find anything that find / -name *test* does, but no more.

I've run `sudo updatedb`.

My home dir access right:

```
/ 
➜ ll
drwxr-xr-x - root 17 Jul  2022 home/
drwxr-xr-x - root 16 Apr 21:44 usr/

/home 
➜ ll
drwxr-xr-x - username 16 Apr 21:51 username/
```

It does seem that `plocate` couldn't access files and directories under my home dir, but it has the same access right as `usr`. I don't understand why `plocate` can see `usr` but not files and dir under `home`.

##### 2. Results are different when running as `sudo`

The results are different when I run `plocate` as `sudo`.

Below is regular `locate`:

```bash
➜  locate ranger
/usr/bin/ranger
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ranger
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ranger_fm-1.9.3-py3.10.egg-info
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ranger/__init__.py
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ranger/__pycache__
```

Below run as `sudo`:

```bash
➜  sudo locate ranger
/root/.config/ranger
/root/.local/share/ranger
/root/.local/share/ranger/bookmarks
/root/.local/share/ranger/history
/root/.local/share/ranger/tagged
/usr/bin/ranger
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ranger
/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ranger_fm-1.9.3-py3.10.egg-info
```

I can see results in my home directories (i.e., first 5 results).

### What I want

I'd like to be able to search my home directory with `plocate` the way I can do so with `mlocate`. In other words, I expect results from home directory when using `plocate`:

```
$ locate home
/home
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d
/etc/apparmor.d/tunables/home.d/site.local
/etc/systemd/homed.conf
/home/username
/home/username/.bash_history
/home/username/.bash_profile
/home/username/.bashrc
/home/username/.cache
/home/username/.cargo
```

Comment: What do you get when you take `fzf` out of the loop? With it this is not a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please see the updated session "2. Results are different when running as sudo".

Comment: That new section looks exactly as expected. `root` can only see files in their own directory.  Non-`root` user cannot see into `root`'s home. I'm still not understanding what you are asking. My original comment still stands; take out the `fzf` filtering and tell us _what you expect to happen._

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Hello I've updated the question. I've taken out `fzf` and restructured the question. Thank you again for following up my question. I appreciate it.

Comment: Looking at the [man page](https://plocate.sesse.net/plocate.1.html), it seems that you may have an alias or something setting the `-b` option because it is ignoring `home` when it's part of the path. Does 'which locate' say it's an alias or something?

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco Thank you for getting back to me. I've found the solution after consulting with `plocate` author. Thank you and have a good day!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL:DR: if you're using `btrfs`, do the following:

1. edit `/etc/updatedb.conf`
2. replace `PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS = "yes"` with `PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS = "no"`
3. save the file
4. update the db with `sudo updatedb`
5. test again with `locate home` to see any outputs from `home` directory.

### Explanation

I contacted `plocate` author and he kindly sent me to the right direction with the following reply:

> 90% of these issues seem to be btrfs misconfigurations. You don't say which
> filesystem you're running, but if so, see the updatedb.conf man page under
> PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS and check your fstab.

I'm indeed using `btrfs` (to check: `lsblk -f`).

Consulting `man updatedb.conf` gives the following:

> PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS
>
> One of the strings 0, no, 1 or yes.  If PRUNE_BIND_MOUNTS is 1 or yes, bind mounts are not scanned by updatedb(8).  All file systems mounted in the subtree of a bind mount are skipped as well, even if they are not bind mounts.  As an exception, bind mounts of a directory on itself are not skipped.  Note that Btrfs subvolume mounts are handled internally in the kernel as bind mounts (see btrfs-subvolume(8)), and thus, may get skipped if you have also mounted the filesystem root itself.  To counteract this, make your root directory a Btrfs subvolume, too.
>
> By default, bind mounts are not skipped.

For solution, please see the above TL;DR.

Comment: That's downright insane. Hopefully the `plocate` author will add that caveat to the docs.